# Dynamic n in function LAG<n> (variable) SAS_part2

Tags: sas, sas-macro

do you know how to use n in function LAGn(variable) that refer to another macro variable in the program-> max in my case **by V1**?

```
   data example1;
input V1 value V2;
datalines;
a 1.0 2.0
a 1.0 1.0
a 1.0 1.0
b 1.0 1.0
b 1.0 1.0
;       

proc sql;
  select max(V2) format = 1. into :n
  from example1;
quit;

data example1;
  set example1;
  by V1;
  lagval=lag&n(V2);
  run;
```

Code from user667489 and works for one column. **Now n changes by V1.** 
I expect:

```
          MAX LAG
a 1.0 2.0  2  .
a 1.0 1.0  2  .
a 1.0 1.0  2  2
b 1.0 1.0  1  .
b 1.0 1.0  1  1
;
```

Comment: Why are taking the maximum of the two variables in ONLY the FIRST observation of EXAMPLE1 and placing it into the macro variable N?  What are you actually trying to find the maximum of?  How do you know it is an integer? Why do you want to use that as the N in the LAGn() function calls?  This is beginning to look like an X-Y problem.  What is the real problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps there is another solution that does not need LAG() or macro variables.

Comment: Show what result to you want for your given input data will perhaps help to clarify what you are trying to do.  For code generation problems like this it is also important to show the code you want to generate.

Comment: What do you "now n changes"? Is n going to change during the data-step? One thing to keep in mind is that `lag1(x)` just returns the value of `x` had the last time `lag(x)` was called. Similarly, `lag2(x)` just returns the value `x` had when `lag(x)` was called two times ago.

Comment: I added more information. I need function LAG per group.

Comment: Are you saying for group with V1='a' you want LAG2(value) and for group with V1='b' you want LAG1(value)?  Again **show your expected results**.

Comment: I added what result I expect

Comment: I'm thinking about crazy approaches involving an array of lags, or maybe a hash table.  Is there a limited set of values for max(V2)?  Like always 1, 2, or 3?  Or do you need to support any lag length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget about LAG(). Just add a counter variable and join on that.

Let's fix your example data step so it works.

```
data example1;
  input V1 $ value V2;
datalines;
a 1 2
a 1 1
a 1 1
b 1 1
b 1 1
;
```

Now add a unique row id within each BY group.

```
data step1;
  set example1;
  by v1;
  if first.v1 then row=0;
  row+1;
run;
```

Now just join this dataset with itself.

```
proc sql ;
 create table want as
   select a.*,b.v2 as lag_v2
   from (select *,max(v2) as max_v2 from step1 group by v1) a
   left join step1 b
   on a.v1= b.v1 and a.row = b.row + a.max_v2
 ;
quit;
```

Results:

```
Obs    V1    value    V2    row    max_v2    lag_v2

 1     a       1       2     1        2         .
 2     a       1       1     2        2         .
 3     a       1       1     3        2         2
 4     b       1       1     1        1         .
 5     b       1       1     2        1         1
```

Hopefully your real use case makes more sense than than this example.

Answer (score 0):

The `LAG<n>` function is an in-place stack of fixed depth that is specific to it's code use location and thus step state at invocation.  The stack is of depth  and can not be altered dynamically at runtime.

A dynamic lag can be implemented in SAS DATA step using a hash object.  The double DOW technique allows a group to be measured and then subsequently it's items operated upon.

Sample code

This example uses a defines a `hash` object that maintains a stack of values within a group.  A first DOW loop computes the maximum of a field that becomes the dynamic stack height.  The second DOW loop iterates of the group and retrieves the lag value while also building up the stack for future item lags.

```
* some faux data;

data have (keep=group value duration);
  do group = 1 to 10;
    limit = ceil(4 * ranuni(6));
    put group= limit=;
    do _n_ = 1 to 8 + 10*ranuni(123);
      value = group*10 + _n_;
      duration = 1 + floor(limit*ranuni(123));
      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

* dynamic lag provided via hash;

data want;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    retain index lag_value .;
    declare hash lag_stack();
    lag_stack.defineKey('index');
    lag_stack.defineData('lag_value');
    lag_stack.defineDone();
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.group);
    set have;
    by group;
    max_duration = max(max_duration, duration);
  end;

  * max_duration within group is the lag lag_stack height;

  * pre-fill missings ;
  do index = 1-max_duration to 0;
    lag_stack.replace(key: index, data: .);
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    lag_stack.replace(key: _n_, data: value);
    lag_stack.find(key: _n_ - max_duration);
    output;
  end;

  drop index;
run;
```

Another technique would involve a fixed length ring-array instead of a hash-stack, but you would need to compute the maximum lag over all groups prior to coding the DATA step using the array.